# How to paginate a relationship result in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pagination

How do you paginate the following line

```
$posts = Category::where('name', request('category'))->firstOrFail()->posts;
```

in the function below

```
public function index()
    {
        $categories = category::all();

        if (request('category')) {
            $posts = Category::where('name', request('category'))->firstOrFail()->posts;

        } else {
            $posts = post::where('status', 1)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(5);
        }


        return view('user.blog', compact('posts', 'categories'));
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the actual relationship method to get access to the query builder:

```
$posts = Category::where('name', request('category'))
    ->firstOrFail()
    ->posts()
    ->paginate(5);
```

See the Eloquent docs on [Relationship Methods Vs. Dynamic Properties](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#relationship-methods-vs-dynamic-properties) for reference.